# How to use seaborn to draw boxplot by choosing specific row?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

| index | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | up |
| 1 | A | down |
| 2 | A | up |
| 3 | A | up |
| 4 | B | down |
| 5 | B | up |
| 6 | B | down |
| 7 | B | up |
| 8 | C | up |
| 9 | C | up |
| 10 | C | down |
| 11 | C | down |
| 12 | D | up |
| 13 | D | down |
| 14 | D | down |
| 15 | D | up |

For example, I want to draw a boxplot by using seaborn to show values in (variable =A and variable=B). How can I solve it?

AS before, the row table contain attributes{"variableA", "variableB","variableC","variableD","value"}

so I can use :
`sns.boxplot(x=df["variableA"],y=df["variableB],order=["up","down"])`

And now I got a melt table(tidy dataframe). How to draw the same picture?

Comment: For a boxplot you'd need numeric values.  But your 'value' column seems to be all strings.  Maybe `sns.countplot(data=df, x='variable', hue='value')` makes some sense here?  If your dataframe has been created using `pd.melt()`, you probably forgot to add `id_vars=` to indicate the columns you want to carry along.

Answer (score 0):

You can select B and A from variable by

`df.loc[(df.variable == "A") & (df.variable == "B")]`

Then Transpose the df by:

`df_T = df.loc[(df.variable == "A") | (df.variable == "B")].T`

Then sns:

`sns.boxplot(x='variable', y = 'value', data = df_T)`

Comment: `df_T` will be an empty DataFrame ;)

Comment: sorry I used the & operator instead of the |. I fixed it :) But it won't work because box plots use numerical variables. So you could use a `countplot` instead

Comment: Better, use `isin`, I didn't check the rest of the logic ;)

Comment: yes that works too